# Order/Sort array map items based on the specific value retaining actual order for rest of the items in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to order array items based on a specific value. my array values are as follows

```
var items = [
  {color: "red" …}
  {color: "green" …}
  {color: "orange" …}
  {color: "blue" …}
]
```

what I'm trying to achieve is

```
["blue, red, green, orange"]
```

only specified value i'e "blue" should be the first item and the rest of the array items should retain their actual order.

here is the code I have so far

```
items.sort((a, b) => 
(b.color === 'blue') - (a.color === 'blue') || a.color.localeCompare(b.color))
```

the above code sorts item "blue" to the top as desired however rest of the items order is not correct

```
["blue, green, red, orange"]
```

however, the desired result is

```
["blue, red, green, orange"]
```

Comment: instead of sorting, you can do `a.filter(first-things).concat(a.filter(not-first-things))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const items = [{color: "red"}, {color: "blue"}, {color: "green"}, {color: "orange"}, {color: "blue"}];

const orderedColorsArr = [
  ...items.filter(({color}) => color==="blue"), 
  ...items.filter(({color}) => color!=="blue")
].map(({color}) => color);
const res = [orderedColorsArr.join(", ")];

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need an array with the colors, then you need to access the strings instead of not given properties and then sort only by the delta of the comparisons with the wanted top color.

```js
const
    items = [{ color: "red" }, { color: "green" }, { color: "orange" }, { color: "blue" }]

items.sort((a, b) => (b.color === 'blue') - (a.color === 'blue'));

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For unstable environments

```js
const
    items = [{ color: "red" }, { color: "green" }, { color: "orange" }, { color: "blue" }],
    order = items.reduce((m, o, i) => m.set(o, i + 1), new Map);

items.sort((a, b) =>
    (b.color === 'blue') - (a.color === 'blue') ||
    order.get(a) - order.get(b)
);

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i'm using array object so it's not possible to convert it into a string

Comment: please add the original data, if possible.

Comment: the sort function simply doesn't work though it works only with localeCompare

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't look like you're sorting anything here. So why even use sort?

Try something like splicing the "blue" element off after getting the index from an indexOf function, then just inserting it at the beginning off the array.

```
let items= [
  {color: "red"},
  {color: "green"},
  {color: "orange"},
  {color: "blue"}
];
const removedElement = items.splice(items.indexOf({color: "blue"}),1);
//or alternatively items.unshift(removedElement[0])
items= [...removedElement,...items].map(item=> item.color).join(",");
const result = [items]
console.log(result);
//["blue,red,green,orange"]
```

Another approach you could take is, filter out the non blue elements, filter out the blue elements and just make a new array with these two.

```
const result = [[...items.filter(item => item.color==="blue"), ...items.filter(item => item.color!=="blue")].map(item=>item.color).join(",")];
console.log(result);
// ["blue,red,green,orange"]
```

Comment: i need to match based on the string "blue" not the index

Comment: @sam I updated the answer based on the changes to your question, but the answer is mostly the same. You're not matching based on index, you're just finding which index to make the splice.

Comment: there are syntax errors in the your code, so modified it like this, still it doesn't work  const sortedArray = [...this.props.items.filter(item => item.color === "blue"), ...this.props.items.filter(item => item.color !== "blue")];

Comment: @sam my bad, i modified a const. Anyways, i updated the answer with what your expected output is

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way is to map and filter without mutation main array

```js
let items= [
  {color: "red"},
  {color: "green"},
  {color: "orange"},
  {color: "blue"}
];

const newarr=[];
    
const arr = items.filter(el => el.color == "blue" ?newarr.push({color:"blue"}) : el);
              
const arr1 = items.filter(el => el.color !== "blue" ? newarr.push(el) : "");
        
console.log(newarr.map(el=>el.color))
```